# jQuery slideDown() not working correctly with AJAX result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want is a mouse hovers over a username, it should slide out the full user name that is is `display: none;` in CSS.
This works fine, however if you click on the **Load more** button, this loads the remaining comments via AJAX and append it to the 
existing ones but if you hover over username of one of them, it display the fullname of all the user names with exception of the first two.

**HTML:**

```
<div class = 'rows'>
    <div class='feed_blocks'>
        <div class='feeds'>
        <!-- user post goes here -->
            <div class = 'comment_data'>
                <div class = 'per_comment'> <!-- two comments are displayed first -->
                    <a href = '#'><p class = 'usernames'>username</p></a>
                    <div class = 'commenter_details'>
                        <p> commenter_full_name </p>
                    </div>
                    <p>comments..</p>
                </div> <!-- end of div per_comment -->
                <div class = 'morecomments'><p> Load more </p> </div>
            </div><!-- end of div comment_data -->
        </div><!-- end of div feeds -->
    </div><!-- end of div feed_blocks -->
</div><!-- end of div rows -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.commenter_details {
background: cadetBlue;
color: white;
position: absolute;
padding: 3px;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-left: 10px;
z-index: 100;
display: none;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.per_comment').on('mouseenter', ".usernames", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parents('.per_comment').find('.commenter_details').slideDown(100);
});
$('.feeds').on('mouseleave', ".usernames", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parents('.per_comment').find('.commenter_details').hide();
});
```

AJAX:

```
<div class = 'per_comment'> <!-- two comments are displayed first -->
    <a href = '#'><p class = 'usernames'>username</p></a>
    <div class = 'commenter_details'>
        <p> commenter_full_name </p>
    </div>
    <p>comments..</p>
</div> <!-- end of div per_comment -->
```

Any help that will enable have a work around this will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Whats the mixup of html/css/jquery?

Comment: You need to show the HTML after the AJAX load. My guess is it doesn't look exactly as the initial load for some reason.

Comment: I have added the AJAX HTML code... @Michael_B

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', ".usernames", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parents('.per_comment').find('.commenter_details').slideDown(100);
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', ".usernames", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parents('.per_comment').find('.commenter_details').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KHd8w/5/

Comment: This works only when AJAX is returning just one comment. I have more than one comment that are returned via AJAX.

Comment: This is why I believe the html your building after the ajax load is different for some reason.

Comment: You are right. Realized that AJAX response are buried within `.per_comment` and then having other `.per_comment` within it.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. Check this as the answer if it is sufficient.